# temporary TEMPLATE_DIRS override for testing does not work

Tags: django, django-testing

For testing a custom templatetag i need to test a function that returns a rendered template. To be able to compare the output without having to know about the user-generated production template (which is going to change every now and then), i try to override the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting. Looks like a perfect use-scenario for the new override_settings decorator of Django 1.4:

```
@override_settings(TEMPLATE_DIRS='%s/templates' % os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) )
    def test_render_as_list(self):
        self.node.type = 'list'
        self.node.listtemplate = 'testtemplate.html'
        self.node.items = ['a', 'b', 'c']

        # these lines print the correct path to the template
        from django.conf import settings
        print(settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS)

        # inserted debug trace here
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()            

        response = render_as_list(self.node, self.context)
        self.assertEqual(response,'item a, item b, item c')
```

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
- project
    - app_to_test
        - fixtures
        - templatetags
        - tests
            __init__.py
            test_templatetags.py (containing the test shown above)
            templates
                testtemplate.html
```

As far as i understand my code, the settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS should now point to

```
/some/path/project/app_to_test/tests/templates
```

The lines to print the new settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS value show that the decorator worked, but still the render_as_list function returns

> TemplateDoesNotExist: testtemplate.html

I'm stuck with that since hours now, and just can't find what else to try.

**edit:**
path creation is working, the file exists, but Django still doesn't load the template:

```
ipdb> from django.conf import settings
ipdb> path = settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
ipdb> templatename = path+'testtemplate.html'
ipdb> templatename
'/Volumes/Data/project/my_app/tests/templates/testtemplate.html'
ipdb> template.loader.get_template(templatename)
*** TemplateDoesNotExist: /Volumes/Data/project/my_app/tests/templates/testtemplate.html
ipdb> f = file(templatename)
ipdb> f
<open file '/Volumes/Data/project/my_app/tests/templates/testtemplate.html', mode 'r' at 0x102e95d78>
ipdb> f.read()
'testtemplate content'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` needs to be a sequence of one or more strings, not a single string. It's trying to use each character of the string as its own directory.

Try:

```
@override_settings(TEMPLATE_DIRS=['%s/templates' % os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))] )
```

If you need to escape whitespace, you can use:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)).replace(' ', r'\ ')
```

---

You show a file called

```
            testtemplate.py
```

and your error says

```
 TemplateDoesNotExist: testtemplate.html
```

and your code says

```
    self.node.listtemplate = 'testtemplate.html'
```

it's looking for an `.html` file, while your file is `.py`.

Comment: The real file's name is 'testtemplate.html'. Updated my question to correct this.

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. But only in combination with entering the path manually, with whitespace escaped. Doesn't os.path.dirname or os.path.abspath escape whitespace?

Comment: No, I'm sure they don't escape whitepace, since that isn't always needed. I added a version that manually does it to my answer.

Comment: Hi agf. I'm sorry, but my previous comment about the test working now was a mistake. I did comment out the important line during testing, and somehow forgot about that while reading your answer 8(. So back to the strange behaviour, which is even stranger now: please see my question edit.

Comment: Ok, got it. As your tip with passing a list to TEMPLATE_DIRS instead of a string was critical, i'm going to accept your answer.